# Tailwind CSS - Second line should be a new line in mobile view

Tags: tailwind-css

How can i make the second line to display as a new line with the horizontal scroll enabled

Each new line should add to the bottom

https://play.tailwindcss.com/AkDQ2ef5mI?size=354x720

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="flex mx-2 space-x-1 text-center overflow-x-auto md:overflow-x-hidden md:space-x-0 md:grid-cols-12 md:gap-1 md:grid">
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>

      <!--second line -->
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create two divs under the parent and then change the parent div to `flex-col` or `flex-row` depending on the device. This way you can achieve the desired result.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/pURsrFHUno?size=758x720

```
<div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row mx-2 space-x-1 text-center overflow-x-auto md:overflow-x-hidden md:space-x-0 md:grid-cols-12 md:gap-1 md:grid">
      <div class="flex flex-row">
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex flex-row">
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
        <div class="border-2 border-black">test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add flex-col  in next div followed by body tag

flex-col

https://play.tailwindcss.com/LoGAnm9EaI?size=354x720

Comment: I need the second row to start as a new line with horizontal scroll enabled. The second row should be a new row